# Passing parameters between two JSP in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem transferring data between two jsp
There are two controllers in which the first one accepts the input data, second generate lines with using this params

First controllers group receives two params

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String ProjectSizePost(
      @RequestParam("countSprints") Integer countSprints,
      @RequestParam("countWorkers") Integer countWorkers) {
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(countSprints);

    return "project/project_size";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String projectSizeGet() {

    return "project/project_size";
  }
```

And his jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Size</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%--<c:forEach var="inputLine" begin="1" end="4">
            <td><input type="text" name="projectManagerId" size="70" value={count} ></td><br>
    </c:forEach>--%>
    <form action="/project/show_size" method="post" name="/project/show_size"
          commandName="projectSizeForm">
    <tr>
        <td>Count of sprints:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="countSprints" size="70" value = ${countSprints}  ></td>
    </tr> <br>
    <tr>
        <td>Count of workers:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="countWorkers" size="70" value = ${countWorkers}  ></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <input type="submit" value="Next page"/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second controller and jsp must take params from first jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String createProject(
      @RequestParam("projectId") Integer id,
      @RequestParam("name") String name,
      @RequestParam("startDate") String startDate,
      @RequestParam("endDate") String endDate,
      @RequestParam("projectStatus") OCStatus projectStatus,
      @RequestParam("projectManagerId") Integer projectManagerId) {
    MapperDateConverter mdc = new MapperDateConverter();
   *//*Project project = new Project.ProjectBuilder()
        .projectId(BigInteger.valueOf(id))
        .name(name)
        .startDate(mdc.convertStringToDate(startDate))
        .endDate(mdc.convertStringToDate(endDate))
        .build();
    project.setProjectStatus(projectStatus);
    project.setProjectManagerId(BigInteger.valueOf(projectManagerId));*//*
    //projectDao.createProject(project);
    return "project/create";
  }
```

And second jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <form action="/project/create" method="post" name="/project/create"
               commandName="projectForm">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <h2>CreateProject</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Project Id:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="projectId" size="70" value = ${projectId} ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Project Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" size="70" value = ${projectName} ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>StartDate (mm/dd/yyyy):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="startDate" size="70" value = ${startDate} ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EndDate (mm/dd/yyyy):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="endDate" size="70" value = ${endDate}  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="projectStatus" size="70" value = ${status}  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Project Manager:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="projectManagerId" size="70" value = ${pmId}  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Count of sprints</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="countSprints" size="70" value = ${countSprints}  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Count of sprints</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="countWorkers" size="70" value = ${countWorkers}  ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Create"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Params **countSprints** and **countWorkers**

Comment: it looks like you have two controller post methods that are mapped to "/create": `@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)` doesn't Spring alert you about that? or are the controllers annotated with different paths?

Comment: oh, sorry, yes. I commented all second controller, because dont have any ideas